# SimpleXML and print_r() - why is this empty?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi there here is my xml file: (thefile)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://nts-de-osm1-pxc/webservices/">
  <Item xmlns:q1="http://systinet.com/wsdl/com/osm/webservices/service/" xsi:type="q1:Document">

    <q1:attributes>
      <q1:Attribute>
        <q1:dataDictionary xsi:nil="true" />
        <q1:dataType>string</q1:dataType>
        <q1:displayName>AEND_DATUM</q1:displayName>
        <q1:key>false</q1:key>
        <q1:name>AEND_DATUM</q1:name>
        <q1:searchable>true</q1:searchable>
        <q1:userAttribute>true</q1:userAttribute>
        <q1:value>10.05.10</q1:value>
      </q1:Attribute>
      <q1:Attribute>
        <q1:dataDictionary xsi:nil="true" />
        <q1:dataType>string</q1:dataType>
        <q1:displayName>AEND_PRUEF_DATUM</q1:displayName>
        <q1:key>false</q1:key>
        <q1:name>AEND_PRUEF_DATUM</q1:name>
        <q1:searchable>true</q1:searchable>
        <q1:userAttribute>true</q1:userAttribute>
        <q1:value>10.05.10</q1:value>
      </q1:Attribute>
    </q1:attributes>
  </Item>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

Here is my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($thefile);
print_r($xml);
```

This is the output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

Why is this Empty?

Answer (score 12):

Don't use print_r() or var_dump() to inspect a SimpleXMLElement, they won't necessarily work on them because SimpleXML uses lots of magic behind the scene. Instead, look at what [`asXML()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml) returns.

In your case, it doesn't show `<q1:attributes/>` because they're not in the same namespace.

### Edit

To access those namespaced nodes, there are many different ways, [most of them discussed here at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bsimplexml+%2Bnamespace). If you can't work it out, please open a new question, since the subject is different. Here's 3 ways to access those elements:

```
$ArrayOfItem->Item->children("http://systinet.com/wsdl/com/osm/webservices/service/");
$ArrayOfItem->Item->children('q1', true);
$ArrayOfItem->Item->xpath('//q1:Attribute');
```

Comment: sXML() shows me the xml file, but how to select a single node now? 

echo $xml->ArrayOfItem->Item->attributes->Attribute[0]->value; dosen't show anything

Answer (score 1):

The simpleXML parser should provide a meaningful error message that you can fetch and output. Check out the example code in the [documentation on `libxml_get_errors()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php).

Comment: @sschnake @pinaki is pointing out at least one grave error, isn't he? (the missing closing tag)

Comment: Yeah, the XML was invalid (I have fixed the original post) and raised at least 3 PHP warnings. Check your error_reporting level. Try adding `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your scripts, otherwise you'll miss so many of those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You are missing the closing tag for q1:attributes.
- SimpleXML cannot handle `<q1:Attributes>` type tags. I changed it to `<q1>` and it works till that tag.

I think you need [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) parser here

Comment: I have fixed the XML. As for the rest, SimpleXML supports namespaces, no problem here.