# SimpleXML - echo / print_r return different values

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to convert some xml into a json object using PHP.

This should be working, yet for some bizarre reason it is failing.

Could someone provide some input.

```
// Loop Through images and return the right one.
$i = 1;
foreach($page->image as $image) {
    if ($i == $_GET['id']) {
         echo json_encode(array(
            'background' => $image['bgColor'],
            'image' => $image['source'],
            'caption' => $image['caption']
         ));
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This code returns the following.

```
{"background":{"0":"000033"},
 "image":"0":"0210e849f02646e2f5c08738716ce7e8b3c1169112790078351021245495.jpg"},
 "caption":   {"0":"Frog"}}

print_r($image['bgColor']); shows 'SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 000033 )'

echo $image['bgColor']; shows '000033'
```

How do I parse values like the echo statement instead of the print_r statement. Why are these different?

Comment: Why are you using print_r when you don't seem to understand what it actually does? print_r() displays information __about__ a variable

Comment: An example that namespaced children are not displayed in `print_r` is in: [SimpleXML and print_r() - why is this empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3109302/367456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are these different

Because these variables are not strings internally, but `SimpleXMLElement` type objects that get converted into strings when output by `echo`.

To use the values elsewhere,I usually do an explicit cast:

```
$bg_color = (string) $image['bgColor'];
```

A canonical question regarding casting a simplexml element into a string is here:

- [Forcing a SimpleXML Object to a string, regardless of context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/416548/367456)