# SimpleXML not loading all fields

Tags: php, xml, rss, xml-serialization, simplexml

For some reason my SimpleXML implementation is not grabbing all the data:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/feed');
print_r($feed);

#This leaves out <media:thumbnail> and <dc:creator>
```

What's going on?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with namespaces, but can't tell more without a XML sample.

Comment: `print_r()` only displays children belonging to the same namespace as their parent. There are many quasi-identical questions around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML and print_r() - why is this empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109302/simplexml-and-print-r-why-is-this-empty)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `children` method, specifying the namespace. The default access and iteration methods only operate on the default namespace.

See [here](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302) for an example.

EDIT: Broken link above, [see here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019003548/http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302) for the last version available from Wayback.