# simplexml parse xml only version

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have to parse automatic generate XML files to PHP, without success.

I'm fetching a folder with XML files and each file has to be parsed. The weird thing is, that I only get the version as output.

My code:

```
$xml_folder = "/var/www/sitename/xml_folder/";
$xml_files  = scandir($xml_folder);
$xml_files  = array_diff($xml_files, array('.', '..'));

foreach($xml_files as $file) {
    $xml_file = $xml_folder . $file;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
    print_r($xml);
}
```

Now, my output looks like this:

[image]

The XML looks like a normal generated XML, here is a screenshot preview of it:

[image]

Sure, it's not structured, but any browser can handle it and creates a valid structure.

Is the structure important for `simplexml`?
I tried a bunch of variations to make it work (even with `simplexml_load_string`), but nothing won't work.

Comment: I'm guessing it works fine. Try this: `echo htmlentities( print_r( $xml, 1 ) );`. Your browser just doesn't display the XML tags. Try a view-source on your page, and you'll see it's all there (I hope).

Comment: Just a guess, but your problem may not be XML but use of the `print_r` function. I don't see any reason to expect print_r to output the actual XML.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like it's because of `print_r()`. With `echo htmlentities(print_r($xml,1));` it just outputs the same as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `print_r` for XML, it does not work nicely for xml.
Instead you can use this to show the xml structure

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Check the answer from: [SimpleXML and print_r() - why is this empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109302/simplexml-and-print-r-why-is-this-empty)

> Don't use print_r() or var_dump() to inspect a SimpleXMLElement, they
>   won't necessarily work on them because SimpleXML uses lots of magic
>   behind the scene. Instead, look at what
>   [`asXML()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml) returns.

Comment: Works very good, but how can i loop into the output from `$xml->asXML()`? If I `print_r()` something like `$xml->asx` (like in my screenshot), I just get the error `Trying to get property of non-object`. My goal is to make the whole XML into an PHP array.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array